# Is there a way to print content of a array into a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

I got a script that picks a random word from an array. What I want this to do is to print one of these arrays into a textarea after the user clicks a button.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script>

        var myArray = [
            "Test",
            "Work",
            "Life"
            ];

            var randomItem = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
            document.body.innerHTML = randomItem;
        
        </script>
    </body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the problem? Create a textarea (or text input field) then, give it an ID so you can access it via `document.getElementById`- and then set its `value`.

Comment: Your question does not seem in any way related to the code snippet that you've provided

Comment: your code in working good whats the problem if you wanted to print results in specific element select that element using `document.querySelector("textarea").innerHTML = "val"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select your text area with some javascript methods such as `document.getElementById`, `document.querySelector` and set its value.

```js
const myArray = ["Test", "Work", "Life"];
// const textArea = document.getElementById('my-textarea');
const textArea = document.querySelector('#my-textarea');
function updateTextArea() {
  var randomItem = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
  textArea.value = randomItem;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="my-textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</br>
<button onclick="updateTextArea()">Update Textarea</button>
```